# Server error 415 while uploading Multipart image in Android

Tags: android, image, image-uploading, multipartform-data, multipart

I am receiving Unsupported File Format error from server while uploading Image file over server.

I have followed a web url and have utilised their code to my comfort.

```
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000; // 5 Seconds
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    String authToken;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset,  String authtoken)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;
        this.authToken = authtoken;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", authtoken);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     * @param name field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        long total = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            /*if (listener != null) {
                total += bytesRead;
                //listener.onProgress((int) ((total * 100) / uploadFile.length()));
            }*/
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String finish() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder response = null;

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status + " " + httpConn.getErrorStream());
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

and using this class from AsyncTask like..

```
MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(url, charset, authToken);
            multipart.addFormField("guestId", params[1]);
            multipart.addFilePart("file", new File(params[0]));
            String response = multipart.finish(); // response from server.
```

I am so damn stuck on this, that I am not able to point out my own minor mistake..

May you please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your mime types list on the server first.

Comment: It accepts image as input.. Image upload working fine over Postman

Comment: Other words: multipart uploading via Postman -> ok, via Android - error, right?

Comment: Yes.. Its working over Postman but not over Android

Comment: Seems like it to be some content type issue... but I am not able to figure out what..

Answer (score 0):

I think "URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)" is not returning proper content type. Since you mentioned that you are sending image as a file try hardcoding "image/*" or "image/jpeg"(Incase you know the image type) as the value for "Content-Type" header field  in the addFilePart() method. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Well it is giving the right information like "image/jpeg", but let me try hard coding it once.

Comment: No Luck .. Still same issue.

Comment: Hmmm... "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" try removing that header that you append for file upload. I think that is not necessary.